# Steady state growth of output

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, solow

In the long run Solow steady state, the growth rate of output in a country is g + n. If there is some other country with exactly the same properties of the first country and the same initial conditions, will the combined output of both the countries also grow at g + n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for any A and B
$$
\text{A}\cdot(g+n) + \text{B}\cdot(g+n) = \text{(A+B)}\cdot(g+n)
$$
does indeed hold.